# Mail.app does not fetch mail regularly with Exchange accounts on Lion

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mail.app

I have this stupid symptom with my mac mail since upgrading from 10.6 to 10.7.

I have multiple exchange accounts; a couple times a day the inbox for 1 or 2 of them will be blank, quitting mail and re-opening will re-download all the mail.

Search also *only* works by person, not 'message contains'

So - I made a new user, everything works perfectly.  Symptom gone.

I formatted and restored from time machine, still have the problem.

This is a dev box with tons of customization - I want to properly PURGE the mail and accounts settings at the file system level, since I know a 'new user profile' is a proper fix for the problem.

Emptying the mail folders doesn't fix it, it re-downloads everything and the problem is still there.

Removing the accounts and re-adding doesn't fix it either.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with `Mail.app` on `OSX Lion` which affects Exchange accounts *only* when Mail rules are enabled. All other IMAP/POP accounts work fine with rules. The "fix" I received from my sysadmin was to disable Mail rules — a bit harsh, but in the end I ended up implementing the same set of rules (mostly moving to different mailboxes) server side.

Digging further into this led me to [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15697283#15697283), and it seems the issue, while observed among Exchange users, has also affected others. Some of the suggestions there that worked were (not counting highly specific ones):

- Delete all rules that were formerly in Snow Leopard and recreate them from scratch in Lion.
- Use [MailActOn](http://indev.ca/MailActOn.html), a paid app that costs US$25 to set up your rules. Several users commented positively on its usefulness.

One thing in common with nearly *all* the complaints there (and mine) are that the rules involve *moving* messages to different mailboxes. Simpler ones like highlighting messages still work (for me too). So until this is fixed by Apple, I'd recommend implementing rules that involve *moving* mails on the server side or using the app above.

Comment: Thank you. Mail.app was working fine on Lion but showing empty folder in Mountain Lion. I removed all Mail.app's rules and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

As you are a Developer, I assume some familiarity with Terminal:

```
find Library -name '*[Mm]ail*' -print
```

and delete all stuff relating to Mail. If this doesn't help, repeat the find looking for Exchange stuff.

Comment: That did find a lot of items - thanks

we'll see if it helps/fixes

Answer (score 0):

I have always renamed (and then later deleted) the `~/Library/Mail` folder and `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist` file. Once you relaunch Mail.app, it should ask you to set up an account again.